# torsors on quasi-split groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, vector-bundles, galois-cohomology

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a split connected reductive group scheme over a scheme $X$.

Let $X'\rightarrow X$ an étale Galois cover of group $\Gamma$.

We consider $G$ a quasi-split group scheme over $X$ that splits over $X'$ to $\mathbf{G}$.

How can we describe a $G$-torsor on $X$ in terms of $X'$ and $\mathbf{G}$?

Comment: Is $X$ connected? What do you mean by "quasi-split" in the relative setting? (Just existence of a Borel $X$-subgroup $B$, or also $B$ contains a fiberwise maximal $X$-torus, or...? SGA3, XXIV, 3.9 demands a *further* condition in terms of the scheme of Dynkin diagrams, automatic for semi-local $X$.) Identifying ${\rm{H}}^1(X',\mathbf{G})$ with ${\rm{H}}^1(X,{\rm{R}}_{X'/X}(\mathbf{G}))$ and taking inspiration from Prop. 36 in section 5.4 of Ch. I of Serre's "Galois cohomology" book, the set of such isom. classes is $\mathbf{G}(X')\backslash ({\rm{R}}_{X'/X}(\mathbf{G})/G)(X)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say at the end above that the set of isom. classes of such torsors on $X$ which also split over $X'$ is given by the indicated "double coset" construction.

Comment: I put it in a general situation but you can suppose that $X$ is a curve over an algebraically cclosed field. quasi-split means that you have a pinning defined over $X$

Comment: In your comment above I think you meant to write "split" rather than "quasi-split", so it remains unclear what you mean by "quasi-split" (do you follow SGA3 or have another definition in mind)?  Maybe some context and motivation would help.

Comment: yes, same as SGA3